# How to install GPMC on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

As the title says, how do I install the Group Policy Manager on Windows Server 2003?

When editing Group Policies in AD it  says I should upgrade to GPMC but the link it provides doesn't work. I can't seem to find it doing a Google search either.

Comment: You couldn't find it? Seriously? - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21895

Comment: I could find this one but didn't think it was compatible because i was running SP2... seems to be working now.

Comment: The GPMC SP isn't related to your OS SP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [Group Policy Management Console](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21895).  The Group Policy Management Console should appear in your Start Menu under "Administrative Tools".  You may invoke the tool directly from Run or the command line with `gpmc.msc`.

Comment: It's not in the Administrative Tools list and doesn't let me run it via gpmc.msc. I'm running Windows Server 2003 SP2, Enterprise Edition

Comment: I'm confused, I linked the exact same installer that @joeqwerty did. However, in the comments you claim it is working. Could you clarify?